# inhomogeneous second order ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$u''(t) + 12.25 u(t) = k \dfrac{\cos \omega t}{27}$

The question is SOLVE FOR $x$($t$), $w$. 
As shown in the picture the equation is an inhomogenous 2$^n$$^d$ $ode$.
In the inhomogeneous part, there is more 3 unknowns present and I am not sure how should I continue to solve the question.

I let $x$ = $at$cos($wt$) + $bt$sin($wt$) 
And I got $dx/dt$ = $a$cos($wt$) - $atw$sin($wt$) + $b$sin($wt$) +$bt$cos($wt$)

$d2x/dt2$v = $v$ - $wa$sin($wt$) - $w^2$$at$cos($wt$) + $aw$sin($wt$) - $bw$cos($wt$) - $btw^2$sin($wt$) + $bw$cos($wt$)

I am not sure whether is my working correct.
After all this working I got stuck.
Can anyone help me please.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the problem $u''(t) + 1225 u(t) = k \dfrac{\cos \omega t}{2T}$?

Comment: u''(t) + 12.25u(t)=(kcos(wt))/27

Comment: You should edit your question with that. If you right click on my equation and select "Show Math as: TeX Commands", you can see how to do it. You would just add a dollar sign at the front and back.

Comment: Hi, can you please show me the working again as it didn't appear in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to solve the following DEQ and will use Undetermined Coefficients:

$$u''(t) + \dfrac{49}{4}~u(t) = k \dfrac{\cos \omega t}{27}$$

For the homogeneous part, we have $m^2 + \dfrac{49}{4} = 0 \implies m_{1, 2} = \pm \dfrac{7 i}{2}$.

This leads to:

$$u_h(t) = c_1 \sin\left(\dfrac{7 }{2} t\right) + c_2 \cos\left(\dfrac{7 }{2} t \right)$$

For the particular part, you almost did the correct thing, choose $u_p = a \sin(\omega t) + b \cos(\omega t)$. It is also worth noting that if we had known that $\omega = \dfrac{7}{2}$, then what you did would be correct. However, in this problem, we are solving for a general $\omega$, and that is why we did not do that.

We find:

$$u''_p + \dfrac{49}{4} u_p = -a \omega^2 \sin (\omega t)-b \omega^2 \cos (\omega t) + \dfrac{49}{4} (a \sin (\omega t)+b \cos (\omega t))= k \dfrac{\cos \omega t}{27}$$

We equate like terms and need to solve:

$$a\left(\dfrac{49}{4} - \omega^2\right) = 0 \\ b\left(\dfrac{49}{4} - \omega^2\right) = \dfrac{k}{27}$$

From this, we get $a = 0, b = -\dfrac{4 k}{27(4 \omega^2 - 49)}$.

This give us:

$$u_p(t) = -\dfrac{4 k \cos(\omega t)}{27(4 \omega^2 - 49)}$$

The final solution is:

$$u(t) = u_h(t) + u_p(t)$$

Comment: Why do we let u=asin(wt) +bsin(wt) instead of acos(wt) + bsin(wt)

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much :D